# In vim, how can I delete all lines in a file except the last 100 lines?

Tags: vim

In vim when my cursor is on the first line I can press:

100dd

to delete the first 100 lines.

But how do I delete *all* lines *except* the *last* 100 lines?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In normal mode:

```
G100kdgg
```

In other words:

```
G     -> go to last line
100k  -> go up 100 lines
dgg   -> delete to top of file
```

Comment: simple and elegant. I like it!

Comment: This doesn't work if the buffer has fewer than 100 lines.  It will incorrectly delete all lines because the `100k` part will have no effect.

Comment: @DonCruickshank Wrong, if there's less than 100 lines, `100k` will go to the first line and `dgg` will delete that single line. `k` is being repeated `100` times, so even if there's only 5 lines it'll "bump" the top of the buffer and then stop.  It doesn't pre-check before doing all the actions.  That said, yes, it will incorrectly delete 1 line if you have 100 or less lines in the buffer.  But IMO, this is a more idiomatic usage of vim than the other highly-upvoted answer:  It's a "sentence" of multiple commands, rather than a single more cryptic one.

Comment: @Izkata Indeed you are quite correct about Vim!  For some reason my mind regressed back to Vi where `100k` has no effect in that circumstance.

Comment: @DonCruickshank Ah, that I did not know..  I've only occasionally been forced to use vi when vim wasn't available, and very much disliked it.  Soooo much more limiting.

Answer (score 51):

In ex mode:

```
:1,$-100d
```

Explanation: ":" puts the editor in "ex mode". The d command of ex mode deletes lines, specified as a single line number, or a range of lines. $ is the last line, and arithmetic can be applied to line numbers.

Comment: FWIW this is the better answer, IMHO

Answer (score 11):

An alternative general purpose solution:

```
:%!tail -100
```

You can use any shell command after the `!` to arbitrarily modify the current buffer. Vim starts the command and feeds the current file to `stdin`, and reads the new buffer from `stdout`.